# Angular Momentum Operators: A quick question

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Given $L_+|l,m\rangle \propto |l,m+1\rangle$

and $L_-|l,m\rangle \propto |l,m-1\rangle$

Why isn't it the case that $\langle l,m|L_+L_-|l,m\rangle = 1$? Perhaps naively, but I assumed

$\langle l,m|L_+L_-|l,m\rangle = \langle l,m|L_+|l,m-1\rangle = \langle l,m|l,m\rangle = 1.$

(Where the L's are operators.)

I ask this as I'm trying to calculate $(\Delta L_1)^2$ and the above is involved as I'm using $L_1=\frac{1}{2}(L_++L_-)$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\approx$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you really should use $\propto$ instead of $\approx$ to describe the result of applying
$L_{+}, L_{-}$ to the eigenstate $\mid l,m \rangle$ of angular momentum operators.

In fact, 
$$\begin{cases}
L_{+} L_{-} - L_{-} L_{+} &=& [ L_{+}, L_{-} ] = [ L_x + i L_y, L_x - i L_y ] = -2 i [L_x,L_y] = 2 L_z\\
L_{+} L_{-} + L_{-} L_{+} &=& 2 ( L_x^2 + L_y^2 ) = 2 ( L^2 - L_z^2 )
\end{cases}\\
\implies
\begin{cases}
L_{-}L_{+} &=& L^2 - L_z^2 - L_z\\
L_{+}L_{-} &=& L^2 - L_z^2 + L_z\\
\end{cases}$$
Notice
$$ L^2 \mid l, m \rangle = l(l+1) \mid l, m\rangle
\quad\text{ and }\quad
L_z \mid l, m \rangle = m \mid l, m\rangle
$$
One has
$$\begin{cases}
\langle l, m \mid L_{-} L_{+} \mid l, m \rangle 
&=& l(l+1) - m(m+1) = (l-m)(l+m+1)\\
\langle l, m \mid L_{+} L_{-} \mid l, m \rangle 
&=& l(l+1) - m(m-1) = (l+m)(l-m+1)
\end{cases}$$

The convention is fixing the phases among $\mid l, m \rangle$ such that

$$
L_{\pm} \mid l, m \rangle = \sqrt{l(l+1) -m(m \pm 1)} \mid l, m\pm 1 \rangle
$$

Please note that $L_{+} \mid l, l\rangle = L_{-} \mid l, -l\rangle = 0$. A consequence
for this is for each $l$, there are only $2l + 1$ admissible values of $m$ (i.e $-l, -l+1, \ldots, l-1, l$).

Comment: Ok so my mistake is fogetting the factor $\sqrt{l(l+1)-m(m \pm 1)}$ when I write $L_{\pm}|l,m\rangle \propto |l,m \pm 1\rangle$?

Comment: @Alex, yes, that's the mistake.